# How to structure an application, and driver code for UART - the concept of decoupling the data

Tags: stm32, c, uart, embedded

So I'm writing drivers for UART on STM32 and even though I kind of have an idea on laying out the structure, I'd still want to clarify prior to implementing, and also considering how essential it is to keep the code clean and organized.

So I have `main.c`, `sensor.c` (application file that uses UART layer), `hal_usart.c` (which is the driver file).

I have heard different things regarding how application code should have no clue whatsoever about the driver APIs, and read up an article the other day that you could decouple the sensor code from HAL driver code using function pointers but not sure how I could do that here, and if that will decouple it considering I'm still passing a reference to USART_Handle struct that contains info like baudRate, parityControl, wordLength, reference to `USART_TypeDef` etc.

Below is a snippet of my idea:

````
// main.c
static USART_Handle pUSART;

int main(void) {
   // initialize clocks/HAL 

   // ...initialize USART struct

   // Get data via UART (calling application API)
   GetData(&pUSART);   
}

// sensor.c
void GetData(USART_Handle *pUSART) {
     HAL_USART_TX(); 
     HAL_USART_RX();   // assuming data is stored in one of the struct members
}

// hal_usart.c
void HAL_USART_TX() {} 
void HAL_USART_RX() {}



```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to stackoverflow.com

Comment: I suspect you will need a file that contains the interrupt vector table and the implementation of the interrupt handers.  I suspect you will need the (usually in assembler) the startup file,  I suspect you will need a Linker Command file to place everything in memory where it is expected to be,

Comment: that doesn't help much really. I have that all in place

Comment: @Ariser-reinstateMonica, Who is Monice?   I agree this question should be ask at: stackoverflow.com

Comment: @user3629249 That's an SE-internal thing. It's a dispute about the SE-staff chastising a community member for a lapse in a very intransparent way and suppressing discussion about that later on.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would have something like `stm32_usart.h` + `stm32_usart.c` making up the actual driver. Normally there is no need to have a HAL in between that driver and the application, because UART is pretty straight-forward and simple.

The *only* reason why you'd want a HAL between the application code and the driver is if the application is some sort of serial library: suppose you are implementing a `printf`-like function, an UART error logger or bootloader etc, something that you want to re-use in multiple projects. If so, it would make sense to wrap the UART in an additional HAL so that your serial library code becomes portable between different microcontrollers. That's where "opaque types", function pointers and all that comes in - only then.

If you have no such special requirements, then the additional HAL is just bloat and you should implement the simplest form of a UART driver:

```
// stm32_usart.h
#ifndef STM32_USART_H    
#define STM32_USART_H

typedef enum  // some error handling type for this driver
{
  USART_OK,
  USART_ERR_OVERRUN,
  USART_ERR_FRAMING,
  USART_ERR_INVALID_BAUD,
  ...
} usart_result_t;


usart_result_t  usart_init (uint32_t baudrate_hz, ... 
/* pick parameters to suit whatever functionality you wish the driver to include here, 
   handshaking, partity, stop bits etc */

usart_result_t usart_send (const uint8_t* data, size_t size);

usart_result_t usart_receive (uint8_t* data, size_t buf_size, size_t* data_received);

#endif // STM32_USART_H
```

And that's pretty much it. `stm32_usart.c` implements these functions. The simplest form of calling code might look something like:

```
usart_result_t  result;
result = usart_init(9600, N, 1);
if(result != USART_OK)
{
  /* handle errors */
}
...

do
  result = usart_send(data, size);
while(result == USART_BUSY);

if(result != USART_OK)
{
  /* handle errors */
}
```

And so on, this for the simplest form of busy-wait polling.

You can expand the functionality as needed: perhaps you need an rx interrupt. If so, that one should be in hidden inside the .c file and `usart_receive` should be the one to communicate with the ISR.

(Though if you need to add the interrupt to a vector table written in C, you may have to expose the function prototype of the ISR in the header, so that the vector table can use the ISR name. This is highly MCU-specific but probably not needed in most Cortex M implementations.)

If you need such an interrupt, you'll likely either need a ring buffer ADT or some DMA library (always go with DMA if available, they tend to be painful to set up, but they do wonders for real-time performance). Meaning that stm32_usart.h should include the relevant library for that, but the library calling code will be placed inside the driver.

I always place includes in the header rather than in the .c file, in order to document code dependencies to the one using your code. Nothing is more annoying that grabbing some 3rd party code and getting compiler errors for "missing function blabla". If you have hidden away your code dependencies for the application programmer, then are making it painful for them to trouble-shoot such errors.

Comment: (1). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole concept of HAL. I understand it's an abstraction layer that's supposed to be generic so it could be used between different MCUs without having to change anything. But the cubemx does generate HAL driver files under Driver directory for peripherals (stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.c, stm32f4xx_hal_dma.c). How's that different than the UART driver that I'm writing from a high-level point of view? 
(2). When you say the reason you'd need HAL between the application code and the driver is if the application is some sort of serial library. Are you referring to HAL API?

Comment: @xyf (1) You understand it correctly, ST does not. Their "HAL" is rather just a bunch of wrapper function around "scary register access", but the calling code isn't written in a way that is independent of the hardware peripheral, so it is not HAL, just bloat. Their libs have a pretty bad reputation in general. Obviously, ST have no interest in providing you the means to move away from their MCU to the competition. Though in all fairness, the competitor libs such as Atmel ASF are equally bad.

Comment: @xyf (2) Yes a HAL is a API. You'd use the same header file and implement the functions there in multiple ways depending on hardware. How far you decide to go in the abstraction depends on the complexity of the hardware and your needs for portability.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're kind-of doubling the abstraction. You are right though, (sensor.c) is the only one that should know about the driver APIs (in hal_usart.c). however realize the the HAL *is* the abstraction layer. In the HAL you write generic functions e.g. uart_read(), uart_write(), and in the implementation of those functions you call your hardware specific functions. the HAL functions wrap the driver specific functions. your application code simply uses the HAL's uart_read() and uart_write() calls to do it's business.

as far as structure, you're right, you can use a global struct with function pointers. you could also contain all the extra info such as baud rate etc. here:

```
typedef struct
{
    bool (*read)(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t num_bytes);
    bool (*write)(unsigned char data);

    bool initialized;
    uint32_t *tx_buffer;
    uint32_t *rx_buffer;
    uint32_t rx_read_position;
} MyUart;
```

then you would ASSIGN this struct's read/write functions, but they *must* have the same signature (return value, parameter types must match). e.g.

```
// my read/write functions that hook into the actual driver, lives in sensor.c
bool my_uart_read(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t num)
{
    USART_RX(buffer, num);
    return true;
}

// in my application code (during initialization)
MyUart uart;
uart.read = my_uart_read;
// etc.
```

then your application code could simply call

```
unsigned char buffer[32];
uart.read(buffer, 16);
```

Comment: There's no apparent reason to use function pointers for this, all they do is enabling C++ like syntax. You'd rather use function pointers when there's a case for polymorphism. If you must have a generic UART HAL for example, and then want to inherit that HAL in one instance for STM32, and in another instance for Microchip SAM or whatever. Then you could let the HAL have a function pointer which is set to the driver-specific implementation of the HAL to achieve polymorphism. But for the average UART driver, all of this is completely overkill.